# Prove that subset of Hilbert space is compact

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I encountered the following difficulty while reading a proof in Bosq's Linear Processes in Function Spaces.

Let $(v_j)_{j\geq 1}$ be an orthonormal basis in the real Hilbert space $H$. Let $1=M_1<M_2<M_3<\dotsb$ be a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers, and let $(\ell_k)_{k\geq 1}$ be a positive sequence with $\lim_{k\to\infty}\ell_k=0$. Define the sets
$$
B_k:=\left\{x\in H \;\middle|\; \sum_{j=M_k}^\infty\langle x,v_j\rangle^2\leq\ell_k\right\}
$$
for $k\geq 1$. Prove that the set 
$$
K:=\bigcap_{k\geq 1} B_k
$$
is compact. This type of problem reminds me of the Hilbert Cube. Is this a special case of something more general?

Comment: I don't care how many French intellectuals you are, Bourbaki, but you've been here for 7 years. Surely you'd know by now not to post a PSQ?

Comment: @user793679 PSQ?

Comment: @lcv "Problem Statement Question;" a post that asks a question without any elaboration or context

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since identifying $(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb N} \in \ell^2$ with $\sum_n v_n \in H$ is an isometry of Hilbert spaces, assume WLOG that $H = \ell^2$.

A standard approach for these kinds of problems is as follows: for each $j$, let $x^j = (x^{j}_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ be an element of $K \subset \ell^2$. Our goal is to extract a convergent subsequence; we do so via a "diagonal" argument.

Extract a subsequence $(x^{j,1})_{j \in \Bbb N}$ of $(x^j)_{j \in \Bbb N}$ for which the sequence $x^{j,1}_1$ of first coordinates converges as $j \to \infty$.  Extract a subsequence $(x^{j,2})_j$ of $(x^{j,1})_j$ for which the sequence $x^{j,2}_2$ of second coordinates converges. Proceed for all $k \in \Bbb N$ to find subsequences $(x^{j,k+1})_j$ of $x^{j,k}$ for which the sequence of $k$th coordinates converges.  Note that for all $k$, the sequence $(x^{j,k})_j \in H$ is such that the first $k$ coordinates all converge. The fact that these subsequences are nested ensures that the coordinate sequence $(x^{j,k}_m)_{j \in \Bbb N}$ will have the same limit for all $k \geq m$.

Consider the sequence $(x^{k,k})_{k \in \Bbb N}$. Verify that all coordinates of this sequence converge, which is to say that $x^{k,k}$ converges pointwise. Using the fact that $(x^{k,k})_k \subset K$, show that $x^{k,k}$ also converges in norm.

Comment: Hello, your notations are too much complicated so that it is quite hard to follow your logic. the j and k are so intertwined in a complicated way that I am lost. What's the meaning of "for each k, let xj=(xjn)n∈N be an element of K⊂ℓ2"? and "Extract a subsequence (xj,1)k∈N" because there is no k in the parentheses?, and so on. Could you please rephrase once? Thank you so much.

Comment: @metric To answer your first question, it should be "for each $j \in \Bbb{N}$..." instead of "for each $k$...". I'm sure that was a typo. Basically, Ben is creating an arbitrary sequence of points in $K$. Each point in $K$ is, of course, a sequence of numbers. So, each $x^j$ is a point in $K$ for $j \in \Bbb{N}$, and is the sequence $(x^j_n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$.

Comment: I understood his intention, but just thought that any single typo in any subscript or superscript in this situation would make the whole answer seriously defective and somewhat unreadable.